# onchange Select não funciona - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Olá pessoal estou fazendo o `onchange` na tag `select` mas não esta funcionando, estou usando o plugin `JS` do Google para cidades e estados, exemplo:

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/fn7c57ag/1/

Comment: Você quer que execute a função de popular a cidade mas também execute sua função?

Comment: Aqui está funcionando Chrome47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o seu script `cidadesEstados.js` está setando o evento `.onchange()` no seguinte trecho:

```
this.estado.onchange=function(){this.dgCidadesEstados.run()};
```

com isto o que você definiu no HTML é sobrescrito, então te aconselho a usar um eventListener:

```js
var model = {};
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    model = {
      estado: document.getElementById('estado'),
      cidade: document.getElementById('cidade'),
      change: true
    };    
    new dgCidadesEstados(model);
    
    //preste atenção no addEventListener;
    model.estado.addEventListener("change", myfunction);
  }
});

var myfunction = function (event) {
  alert(event);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ffsolucoesweb.com/ferramentas/cidadesEstados.js"></script>
<label>Estado</label>
<input id="estado" name="estado">
<label>Cidade</label>
<input id="cidade" name="cidade">
```

desta forma você poderá ter mais de um evento ocorrendo no change do select estado.

também aconselho que modifique o `cidadesEstados.js` para usar um `eventListener` sempre que possível:

```
this.estado.addEventListener("change", function(event) { 
    this.dgCidadesEstados.run()
};
```

Comment: Obrigado @Toby, deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar o change com jquery:

`$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#estado").change(function(){ 
      alert(123);
   });
});`

Answer (score 1):

O evento `.onchange` está funcionando corretamente.

Ele está sendo atribuído na linha 91 do arquivo `cidadesEstados.js`

```
this.estado.onchange= function() { this.dgCidadesEstados.run() };
```

No HTML você tenta atribuir a função `myfunction()"` no evento onchange, só é possível adicionar uma função por evento (mas você pode chamar várias funções dentro de uma). Se você quer deixar a sua função no onchange, recomendo refatorar o código e criar um select pois não existe o evento onchange em campo de texto.